# Metadata for PHP files

Tags: php, metadata, meta-tags, meta

I'm currently working in a project for my client. I'm creating a website and used header.php and footer.php for separate header and footer and included them on all the files.

But the issue is that all the files have same Metadata now.

I want to know how can I change metadata for all the files, so that the files contain separate meta title, description, keywords, etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would say that in your instance `header.php` and `footer.php` must only contain info that stays the same for all pages. Page specific info can always be put inside the code of the page itself. It can be done, actually I sm pretty sure most MVC frameworks provide a way to do what you are asking.

Comment: I removed the `stata` tag, which has no obvious rationale,

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and a switch statement to generate different versions of head?/header and footer. For example the page title:

```
switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
    case '/about.php':
        $title = 'About us';
        break;
    case '/index.php':
    default:
        $title = 'Home';
}
```

Then inject the title in your HTML:

```
<head>
    <title><?=$title?></title>
</head>
```

This is the most basic way to get what you asked for.